# how to color input fields chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to add a little something to my chrome extension. What I want to do, is everytime I click in an input field in chrome I want the color (background) to change, Only for that period of viewing the page. I only want to do this when my extension is turned on.

how can I do this?

Comment: Do you know how to do it on a regular site using javascript?

Comment: in html code yes, but not as an extension changing other pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it in javascript then converting it into an extension is very easy.

You need two files:

- Your js file where you do all the work (exactly as if you did it on a regular page). This is called a "content script".
- Manifest file where you describe on which domains your content script should run:

  ```
  {
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
        "css": ["mystyles.css"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
  ```

You can read more about content scripts [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html) and about extension structure in general [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/getstarted.html).